# Searching and Retriving image from a folder

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing a project in MVC4 using c#.
in my project i am storing some group of persons details in database with unique id.and also storing the profile pic of particular person in a folder in my project.(Id number and pic name is same).
in view i want display all these details.Problem is in images. I use the following codes

**View**

```
   @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
       <td><img src="@Url.Action("ImageRetrive", "Member", new {imgname=(item.Id)})" /><br />Rtn. @item.Mem_NA<br />(@item.Mem_Occ)</td>
    }
```

**controller**

```
    public string ImageRetrive(int imgname)
    {
        string keyword=image.ToString();
        string imagefolderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos");
        string currentimage  = new Member().GetImage(imagefolderpath,keyword);
        string fullpath = "~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos/" + currentimage;
        return fullpath;

    }
```

**model**

```
   public string GetImage(string path,string keyword)
    {
       DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] images = di.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo image in images)
        {
            var name = image.Name;
            if (name.Contains(keyword))
            {
                imgname = name;
            }
        }
        return imgname;
    }
```

But i didnot get any output. in the controller the variable fullpath is giving the link. but it can take in . Please help me.

Comment: Why dont you configure complete path of the server location in web.config and use it to retrieve the image

Comment: Because Directory.GetFiles(path) will need to have complete path.

Comment: image.ToString(); as file name? where is the extension?

Comment: @Na Na:i want serach without extention . if the string is in the file name i want to display it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need is [`FilePathResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filepathresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), change your controller code as

```
public FilePathResult  ImageRetrive(int imgname)
{
    string keyword=image.ToString();
    string imagefolderpath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos");
    string currentimage  = new Member().GetImage(imagefolderpath,keyword);
    string fullpath = "~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos/" + currentimage;

    return File(fullpath, "image/png"); //Changed here
}
```

or You can use [FileContentResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filecontentresult%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

```
public FileContentResult Retrive(int imgname)
{
    return File(ConvertToByteArray(YourFile), "image/png"); //Changed here
}
```

Comment: thank you its working. I have one more doubt if in my folder jpg and png images then how i return files.

Answer (score 1):

In your view you pass `imgname` as parameter and in your controller you get `image`.

**Controller**

```
public string ImageRetrive(int imgname){ }
```

Change return path

```
return File(fullpath, "text/plain");
```

Comment: it was worked. but now the problem is that the model is returning only the file name(atually i want that).But  "currentimage" in the controller shows the full path. what is the problem there

Comment: and also the file extention is missing

Comment: simple return currentimage instead of fullpath

Comment: that is not working .actually it shows the path like "c://...." i need ~/Content/Member/MemberPhotos/imagename.jpg/png